# Shell script inside javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, shell

i'm currently trying to make an application which allows video streaming. For this purpose, in my html code i have something like this:

```
</img ... src="http://172.17.23.213:8080/?action=stream ... />
```

The problem is that this IP is constantly changing. So I have to manually change the IP inside the HTML.

I've tried http://local.host:8080/?action=stream but it's not working either. What I'd like to do would be this:

1- This shell command returns the IP of my device:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

2- I'd like to call this command from a JavaScript small function (GETIP) and to store the value in a variable

3- Return that variable in the Javascript function

4- Do this:

```
 </img ... src="GETIP()" ... />
```

Is that feasible? I'm very new with this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

If the url you are trying to call is the same as the server, you don't have to specify the ip. Your img tag should simply use:

```
</img ... src="/?action=stream ... />
```

If the url refers to another server, you would need to call that server in order to get its ip address, which you can't, because you don't have its ip address.

Comment: The URL is the same as the browser but that's is not working :/

Comment: Is it on another port?